Angular routing not working inside remote application in MFE
I am using Angular MFE to launch remote application from shell . When I click on menu from shell application , I am trying to load the remote app route.
First time it is launching successfully whatever remote route I give in shell application. But once remote application loaded , when I click on any button to navigate between remote application modules, it is changing only the URL in the browser but component not rendering.
Note: If I launch remote app separately it is working fine
Please anyone suggest how to handle remote app routing inside shell application.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
